# how to get button click with dynamic parameter in unity 2d version 2019.3.7

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, dynamic

I have below structure, I need to parse every ID on button click, Insort I need ID to another screen. Anyone please help me to do this.

---

***SCREEN 1 :***

---

[image]

---

***expected SCREEN 2 :***

---

Welcome to ID : `[DYNAMIC ID from Last PLAY btn click]`

---

***Software/platform I am working on***
Unity 2D Version 2019.3.7f*, Data come from MongoDB Json

---

```
foreach (var document in playercollection.Find(where14)) 
    {
        var dotNetObj = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(document);
        var jsonstring =    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotNetObj);
         TableClass myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<TableClass>(jsonstring);
        table_data.text = myObject.table_name;
        table_boot.text = myObject.boot;
        table_pot.text = myObject.pot_limit;
        GameObject newitems = Instantiate<GameObject> (itemPrefab, transform);          
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code reference where you are generating the ui.

Answer (score 1):

You can add onclick listener dynamically and pass the id. Assuming you are adding this UI rows dynamically if yes then you can do the following:

```
button.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked("my_id"));//write this in the loop or where you are generating UI rows.

void ButtonClicked(string id)
    {
        
        Debug.Log("Button clicked = " + id);
    }
```

Based on your edited question and assumption itemPrefab has a Button component attached following should work.

```
foreach (var document in playercollection.Find(where14)) 
    {
        var dotNetObj = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(document);
        var jsonstring =    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotNetObj);
         TableClass myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<TableClass>(jsonstring);
        table_data.text = myObject.table_name;
        table_boot.text = myObject.boot;
        table_pot.text = myObject.pot_limit;
        GameObject newitems = Instantiate<GameObject> (itemPrefab, transform);          
        newItems.GetComponent<Button>().AddListener(() => ButtonClicked("my_id"));//use id from the document
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it should be double dot? `<Button>()..AddListener(` there?

Comment: No, sorry it was a typo, I have updated the answer. If my answer is what you were looking for than please accept the answer.